# How to group by date with interval in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("6192513e0fd6ec5ad80376a7"),
    user: "mark.1239",
    connection: ISODate("2021-11-09T23:55:40.342Z"),
    disconnection: ISODate("2021-11-10T01:10:40.342Z")
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("6192513e0fd6ec5ad80376a9"),
    user: "john.9874",
    connection: ISODate("2021-11-02T07:15:42.318Z"),
    disconnection: ISODate("2021-11-02T08:40:42.318Z")
},
...
```

I want to get each connected users by 15 minutes interval.
So in this case, John is connected at 7:30 but also at 8:15.

I can group by connection or disconnection with the 15 minutes interval, but it won't take users connected with connection and disconnection fields outside the 15 minutes interval.

I actually have this but can't find how to modify it to achieve what I want

```
collection.aggregate([
   { 
      "$group": {
           "_id": {
              "$toDate": {
                  "$subtract": [
                       { "$toLong": "$connection" },
                       { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$connection" }, 1000 * 60 * 15 ] }
                   ]
               }
           },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "user": {"$addToSet":"$user" }
      }
   },
   { $sort: {_id: 1} }
])
```

Is it possible to achieve this with mongo only, without javascript ?

Comment: you have 15 minutes(for example 2 dates with difference 15 min), and you want to see that  time which users were online?  can you change the question a bit to be more clear?
giving more sample data, and expected output helps.  Or you want to find all users for each 15 min time? if you want this, when is the starting date?

Comment: You are looking to find how many 15 min connected intervals are there for each user?

Comment: I don't think `$group` is the right operation.  The question seems to imply that you want `john` to appear in each  of the 15-minute counts from when he connected until he disconnected, while `$group` will only include him in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are not fully clear, have a look at this outline:

```
        connection      disconnection
————————————|————————————————|——————————————> t
                                        

 start + end
  x     x   |                |             | NO
        x   |           x    |             | YES/NO?
            |     x     x    |             | YES
            |     x          |    x        | YES/NO?
        x   |                |    x        | YES/NO?
            |                |    x    x   | NO
```

One approach is to generate intervals of 15 Minutes and then filter on these intervals. Could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
         // Determine total min. and max. time. Might be replaced by static values
         min: { $min: "$connection" },
         max: { $max: "$disconnection" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         // Round min/max time to 15 Minute interval
         min: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$min", unit: "minute", binSize: 15 } },
         max: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$max", unit: "minute", binSize: 15 } }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         // Get number of 15-Minute intervals between min and max
         steps: {
            $dateDiff: {
               startDate: "$min",
               endDate: "$max",
               unit: "minute"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         // Generate the 15-Minute intervals
         intervals: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, "$steps", 15] },
               as: "t",
               in: {
                  start: {
                     $dateAdd: {
                        startDate: "$min",
                        unit: "minute",
                        amount: "$$t"
                     }
                  },
                  end: {
                     $dateAdd: {
                        startDate: "$min",
                        unit: "minute",
                        amount: { $add: ["$$t", 15] }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Transpose array to documents
   { $unwind: "$intervals" },
   // Just some cosmetic
   { $project: { data: 1, start: "$intervals.start", end: "$intervals.end" } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            // Filter matching connections (based on outline above)
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               cond: { $and: [{ $lte: ["$$this.connection", "$start"] }, { $gte: ["$$this.disconnection", "$end"] }] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Skip all 15-Minute intervals without any connection
   { $match: { data: { $ne: [] } } },
   // Count users and some cosmetic
   {
      $project: {
         start:1,
         end: 1,
         count: { $size: "$data" },
         user: { $setUnion: "$data.user" }
      }
   }
])
```

Another approach could be `$bucket` but would be difficult, because it works only with numeric values, i.e. you have to twist around `Date` values.

Just a tip: Create a helper function

```
function between(ts, start, end) {
   let ret = {};
   if (typeof ts == "string") {
      ret["$expr"] = { $and: [{ $lte: ["$" + start, "$" + ts] }, { $gte: ["$" + end, "$" + ts] }] };
   } else {
      ret[start] = { $lte: ts };
      ret[end] = { $gte: ts };
   }
   return ret;
}
```

It corresponds to [SQL BETWEEN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp), i.e. `WHERE ts BETWEEN start AND end`

Then you can compose conditions like this

```
{ $match: between("start", "connection", "disconnection") }
{ $match: between(new Date(), "connection", "disconnection") }
```

which makes it much easier to write your query.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, your request does exactly what I need, thank you very much !